# Butchered my python - How to change default python version with multiple installed?

Tags: python, linux, centos, environment-variables

An application I have advised to upgrade my python to 2.7.10, I have 2.7.5 installed and running CentOS 7. I made a poor choice to follow this guide (http://tecadmin.net/install-python-2-7-on-centos-rhel/#) but install of make altinstall, just did make install as I thought I wanted to upgrade my current version. Now some system applications (yum) not longer work. How can I change the path back to /usr/bin/python instead of /usr/local/bin/python?

```
[root@host ~]# which python
/usr/local/bin/python
[root@host ~]# /usr/local/bin/python -V
Python 2.7.10
[root@host ~]# ls -lth /usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 16 Nov 24 19:03 /usr/bin/python -> /usr/bin/python2
[root@host ~]# ls -lth /usr/bin/python2
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 9 Nov 22 22:42 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7
[root@host ~]# ls -lth /usr/bin/python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 7.0K Jun 23 20:42 /usr/bin/python2.7
[root@host ~]# /usr/bin/python2.7 -V
Python 2.7.5
[root@host logs]# ls -lth /etc/environment 
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Oct 29  2014 /etc/environment
[root@host logs]# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
```

Comment: search into the tarball for uninstall. it should be something there. But you could try rm /usr/local/bin/python; the which tool then it will search through $path and will find the next available which should be /usr/bin/python

Comment: Running `make uninstall` in the source directory you installed from might work. If not moving `/usr/local/bin/python` out of the way will get the system python to be used again by default (and that might be enough to unbreak the system).

Comment: I ended up resorting to removing that link from the /usr/local/bin directory. Though I'm not sure why I can't specify 'which' one the PATH should use since there were multiple. Oh well. Thank!

Answer (score 0):

Run `echo $PATH`. You should see that it contains the location to usr/local/bin/python instead of /usr/bin/python. Check the **etc/environment** file to ensure your PATH is correct.

Comment: Thanks - I posted this output. /etc/environment is empty. Path contains BOTH /usr/bin and /usr/local/bin.

Comment: Do you see your path variable being set in the **~/.profile** file?